# Remote event receivers are not firing when OOTB Approval workflows update the approval status of a document

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer, remote-event-receiver

I have a document library in SharePoint Online with remote event receivers to capture item updating and item updated events.

In the library content approval is enabled and the OOTB Approval workflow is attached to do the approval when a major version of the document is published. When approval is completed or rejected using this approval workflow the document's approval status gets updated.

However this change in approval status is not firing the item updated and item updating event receivers attached to the document library.

Is this an expected behavior in SharePoint Online...???

Comment: I believe this is expected because otherwise, the update in status would cause a change in version, which would lead to an infinite approval process.

Comment: I managed to figure out the reason why it was not getting captured in the remote event receiver. It seems the client context is null in the event receiver when the item updating/updated event is triggered for approval status change using the approval workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this workaround.

`Added a custom field Status and in the approval workflow update the custom Status field.`

Probably this way, your Event Receiver might get triggered.

Comment: Editing the OOTB approval workflow does not seem to be a possible option for me because its attached during the library creation step.

Comment: Can you replicate approval wf in a custom wf and then follow my suggested answer.

Comment: i know this works when we use custom workflows. I am interested to know why the remote event receivers are not working when OOTB approval workflows are used in a library.

Comment: Not sure about the reason but as mentioned by Eric, it appears to be by design.